# Qt QString "key-value" replace from QHash

Tags: c++, qt, string-parsing, qstring, qhash

I have a QString with content that looks something like this:

"*resolution=[**imagesize**]&quality=[**imagequal**]*".

And I have a `QHash<QString, QString> mDefaults` container that holds a list with some of my 'key' values.
("**imagesize**" and "**imagequal**" are so called 'keys' that I need to replace with values from my hash container)

```
mDefaults.insert("imagesize", "320x240");
mDefaults.insert("imagequal", "standard");
```

My goal is to get a string that will look something like this:
"resolution=**320x240**&quality=**standard**" (Note that "[" and "]" are gone too)

Is there any fast/good way to do this kind of string key-value replacement with Qt library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(QMap::iterator i=mDefaults.begin();i!=mDefaults.end();++i) {
    myString.replace(QString("[%1]").arg(i.key()), i.value());
}
```